# Remove div using just classname

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove below element using javascript/jquery.

```
<p class="classname"><a title="some title" href="#">Hello</a></p>
```

Please note that I don't have the id of the element so how can I remove it using just the class name.

Answer (score 8):

```
$('.classname').remove();
// OR
$([container selector]).remove('.classname');
```

according to the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).

Answer (score 0):

you can select items by their class using the following syntax

```
$(".classname")
```

So to remove this item it would be

```
$('.classname').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the link is unique but the paragraph with the classname is not and you only want to remove this single element, search for the link first:

```
$("a:contains('Hello')").parent().remove();
```